How to mount a GCP Cloud Storage volume in GCP Cloud Run service?
I'm trying to mount a volume type GCP Cloud Storage Bucket in GCP Cloud Run container that runs an official Docker grafana/grafana:10.3.12 image. The volume is configured with mounted path /etc/grafana but when deploy new revision the logs show the following error.

"mkdir: can't create directory '/etc/grafana/provisioning/plugins': No such file or directory"

My Dockerfile and grafana.ini config is the following.
grafana.ini:
GF_PATHS_CONFIG="/etc/grafana/grafana.ini"
GF_PATHS_DATA="/etc/grafana"
GF_PATHS_LOGS="/etc/grafana/logs"
GF_PATHS_PLUGINS="/etc/grafana/provisioning/plugins"
GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING="/etc/grafana/provisioning"

Dockerfile:
FROM grafana/grafana:10.3.12
USER root
COPY --chown=472:0 ./project/grafana.ini /etc/grafana/grafana.ini
COPY --chown=472:0 ./project/provisioning /etc/grafana/provisioning
RUN chown 472 -R /etc/grafana
USER 472
...

The service works well and I can access to Grafana and configure datasources and dashboards but the information isn't persisted in my GCS bucket.

Can you also share your Cloud Run configuration?

Solved modifying the Grafana environment vars
GF_PATHS_CONFIG="/etc/grafana/grafana.ini"
GF_PATHS_DATA="/var/lib/grafana"
GF_PATHS_LOGS="/var/lib/grafana/logs"
GF_PATHS_PLUGINS="/var/lib/grafana/plugins"
GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING="/var/lib/grafana/provisioning"

And the Cloud Run volume should be directly Bucket root not subfolder within.
